# How to sort the items like contacts in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

How to display the a-z letters at left side of screen.whenever click on it display that matching items?please help me out.any samples?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to implement this using the following CodeProject article :-

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166297/Developing-a-Windows-Phone-7-Jump-List-Control

Or you could use the LongListSelector from the Silverlight Toolkit for Windows Phone :-

http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part1-visual-structure-and-api